# Browser URL file extension dropping using springMVC

Tags: spring, jsp, web.xml

I am developing an application using Spring. I am navigating to different pages through out the application. My problem here is,
if i am navigating to the `ABC.jsp` page. In the browser it should shown to be as `IP:port/ABC`, not like `IP:port/ABC.jsp`.

Is there any mechanism in spring to hide the file extension in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am not wrong and you are using sping. So simple do one thing in the controller request mapping drop the extension and in controller setting view page to the model, drop extension in that also. Like

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login")
    public ModelAndView login() {
        return new ModelAndView("login");
    }
```

in the above method i am mapping the controller as login by dropping the extension and in the time of forwarding the model i am dropping the extension. In this case you can forward to the controller without showing the extension in the url.

Answer (score 1):

With a servlet mapping you need to specify each JSP individually like follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>search</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/search.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>search</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/search</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It's easier if all those JSPs are in a common path. E.g. /app/*.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.FriendlyURLServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

with

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF" + request.getPathInfo() + ".jsp").forward(request, response);
```

This assumes the JSPs to be in /WEB-INF folder so that they cannot be requested directly. This will show /WEB-INF/search.jsp on http://example.com/app/search.

Comment: thank you for response Mr.Santino 'Sonny' Corleone. But here i am using spring controller to navigate to the ABC.jsp page. I just want to navigate from the controller to the jsp page without shoowing the file extension.

Comment: so just map the .jsp filename to whatever you want..like this `<servlet>
    <servlet-name>search</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/search.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>search</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/search</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`

Comment: I mean to say that. I am using more than hundred files in my application. I think it is not good practice with the application to write it for more than 100 files like that. Am i right?

Comment: you are right but i have no idea of other ways..check on google

Comment: tq santino. I have tried on google, but can able to find the answer

Comment: http://subinsb.com/hide-file-extensions-in-client-browser-using-htaccess try this also

Comment: and  finally this http://www.tiks.in/articles/tips-and-tricks/hiding-file-extension-using-htaccess/